# Powershell, OOP, Why return $false does not exit Class Method

Tags: powershell

in Powershell 5

I do not understand, when debugging this code, why when the string " of the" is matched at the end of the main string, the method does not perform exit from the Class Method and continues to iterate.

Seems contra-intuitive to me.

Must I use the auxiliary variable and a label combined with break command?

something like here:

```
:JUMPASFOX foreach ($i in (1..10)) {
...{break JUMPASFOX}
```

I thought return $false anywhere causes exit.
I cannot reconcile that my code does not work.

```
Class EndFinder {
    [string[]]$Exclusions_End_Text=@(" of", " of the", " of a", "for a", "for the", " in", " the")
    EndFinder(){}

    [boolean]Contains_Exclusion_At_The_End ([string]$ClipText) {
       #$found=$false
       $this.Exclusions_End_Text |foreach { 
            $exclusion_length=$_.Length
            $clip_length=$ClipText.Length
            if ($exclusion_length -lt $clip_length) {
               $tailing=$ClipText.Substring($clip_length-$exclusion_length,$exclusion_length)
               if ($tailing -eq $_) {
                    #$found=$true
                    return $true
               }
            }
       }
       return $false
       #return $found
    }
}

$kb=[EndFinder]::New()
$kb.Contains_Exclusion_At_The_End("big problem of the")
```

Comment: This happens because you're using `... |foreach {}` (which resolves to `... |ForEach-Object {}`) instead of a real loop - `return` returns control from the scriptblock to the `ForEach-Object` command, which then invokes the next iteration, oblivious to the "intuitive" behavior you're expecting.

Answer (score 2):

As [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) points out in his comment, the [`return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return) keyword when used in the scope of a cmdlet such as `ForEach-Object` will go to the next iteration, similar to what [`continue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_continue?view=powershell-7.2) would do if it was a loop (`for`, `foreach`, `while`, etc).

- Goes to next iteration when the condition is met:

```
0..4 | ForEach-Object {
    if($_ % 2) {
        return 'Odd'
    }
    'Even'
}

Even
Odd
Even
Odd
Even

# Same behavior with script block:

0..4 | & {
    process
    {
        if($_ % 2) {
            return 'Odd'
        }
        'Even'
    }
}
```

- Stops the iteration:

```
foreach($i in 0..4) {
    if($i % 2) {
        return 'Odd'
    }
    'Even'
}

Even
Odd
```

---

I'm assuming you're trying to see if the string provided to your method **ends with** any of the `$Exclusions_End_Text` strings from your class property. If that's the case, this should do it:

```
Class EndFinder {
    hidden [string[]]$Exclusions_End_Text = @(
        " of", " of the", " of a", "for a", "for the", " in", " the"
    )

    # EndFinder(){} => Constructor is not needed here, PS does this by default.

    [boolean] Contains_Exclusion_At_The_End ([string]$ClipText)
    {
        foreach($i in $this.Exclusions_End_Text)
        {
            if($ClipText.EndsWith($i))
            {
                return $true
            }
        }
        return $false
    }
}

$kb = [EndFinder]::New()
$kb.Contains_Exclusion_At_The_End('big problem of the') # => True
$kb.Contains_Exclusion_At_The_End('not ending with any $Exclusions_End_Text') # => False
```

I would personally use a `static` method in this case, I believe it's more appropriate for what you're trying to accomplish:

```
Class EndFinder {
    static [boolean] Contains_Exclusion_At_The_End ([string]$ClipText)
    {
        $Exclusions_End_Text = @(
            " of", " of the", " of a", "for a", "for the", " in", " the"
        )

        foreach($i in $Exclusions_End_Text)
        {
            if($ClipText.EndsWith($i))
            {
                return $true
            }
        }
        return $false
    }
}

[EndFinder]::Contains_Exclusion_At_The_End('big problem of the')
[EndFinder]::Contains_Exclusion_At_The_End('not ending with any $Exclusions_End_Text')
```

Comment: wow, EndsWith  I did not even realize it exists. Thanks

Comment: @John happy to help. please consider accepting the answer if it was useful and solved your doubt